# How to configure spring boot server from java code (on initialization)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, configuration

Due to some circumstances I don't know the location of keystore file in advance. I read some base64 encoded .jks from environment variable, save it to tmp file and then have it's location which I can provide to Spring.

So I can't write

`server:
    ssl:
        key-store: classpath:ssl/server_keystore.jks`

How can I set the keystore location in @Configuration?

Answer (score 0):

So, as I found out, embedded servlet container can be configured by implementing `WebServerFactoryCustomizer`.

Example:

```
@Component
public class MyTomcatWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        Ssl ssl = factory.getSsl();
        ssl.setKeyStore("...");
        ssl.setKeyAlias("...");
        ssl.setKeyStorePassword("...");
        ssl.setKeyPassword("...");
    }
}
```